# How can I implement a stack?

Tags: c#, binary, stack

How can I create a program to convert binary to decimal using a stack in C#?

Comment: Wow, tag wars? Who deleted all the comments? OP?

Comment: I deleted my comment because I wasn't sure if it was right

Comment: No more offensive tags. This is not the place to flame people for their English skills.

Comment: Rich, do you not know what that means? Google it. I think its great to categorize these questions with that tag.

Comment: http://plzsendmethecode.blogspot.com/

Comment: @Jonathon: I am very aware of what it means. It is insulting and has nothing to do with the question and getting it answered.

Comment: @Rich - but it is a homework question though and should be tagged as such.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a hint, this snippet converts a decimal integer to binary using a Stack, you just have to invert the process :-P

```
        int num = 50;
        Stack<int> stack = new Stack<int>();
        while (num != 0)
        {
            stack.Push(num % 2);
            num /= 2;
        }

        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.Write(stack.Pop());
        }
```